# Combining and minifying CSS files - re-basing url(...)s

Tags: css, url, minify

As part of deployment, I'm minifying and combining several CSS files into one. In so doing, though, many `url()`s being used by `background-image` rules etc are being invalidated, as the CSS rules moves from being in one file (in one location) to another.

Are there any CSS minifiers which will re-base these URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UriRewriting); it may help. If it doesn't, tell me and I'll have a go at finding something else.